# SQL - Programmatically rename all table columns in a database

Tags: sql-server-2000

Say I have a table: `UltimateTable`.  It has columns:  `UltimateColumn1`, `UltimateColumn2`.  They should be renamed

`UltimateTable_UltimateColumn1`
`UltimateTable_UltimateColumn2`

I believe I can iterate tables with `sp_MSForEachTable`.  How can I rename all the tables in a single database per the example with T-SQL?

I know a lot of people are not a fan of appending table names to column names when an alias will do.  Get over it.  It's the company standard.

(j/k I hate it too...)

Comment: don't prefix column names with the name of the table. Period. Just don't

Comment: Don't use sp_MSForEachTable. It has the same annoying cursor problems as sp_MSForEachDB (see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx and http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - I **wish** I didn't have to.  As I said in the original post, I hate it.  But, unless you can come on up to my job and convince the lead dev and the DBA to change the company standard then it must be done.  In fact, I gotta go back and do this now because I didn't follow the verbose terrible standard during the dev phase.

Comment: You're developing something *now* on SQL Server 2000? Did you pick your job on purpose? :-)

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - LOL.  Unfortunately yes...I did pick the job.  Its Dallas, no Microsoft's or Google's to pick from here!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Mitch that this is a seriously bad idea and you should fight it to the death. That said, there are easy ways to generate this type of script using the catalog views (*not* sp_MSForEachTable, which still only gets you the table names, not the column names, anyway).

Run this in one window:

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_rename ''' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) 
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + '.' 
  + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ''', ''' 
  + TABLE_NAME + '_' + COLUMN_NAME + ''', ''COLUMN'';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE TABLE_NAME + '[_]%';
```

Now copy and paste the output into a new window. Check it over before executing - and test it on a test database first!

Comment: Thx for bringing up the deficiency of the sp_msforeach... routines. I wasn't aware of that.